# A proof of Stirling's Formula

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, integration, asymptotics

I need to gain understanding of a proof of Stirling's formula. I have read through [Tim Gowers'](http://gowers.wordpress.com/2008/02/01/removing-the-magic-from-stirlings-formula) and [Terence Tao's](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/02/254a-notes-0a-stirlings-formula) but I'm struggling to follow them. How rigorous is this proof, if at all? Thank you.

\begin{equation}
\Gamma(n+1)=n!=\int_0^\infty t^n\mathrm{e}^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t
\end{equation}

Take the log of the integrand:

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{log}(t^n\mathrm{e}^{-t})=n\mathrm{log}(t)-t 
\end{equation}

Let $t=n+\epsilon$, then:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{log}(t^n\mathrm{e}^{-t})&=n\mathrm{log}(n+\epsilon)-(n+\epsilon) \\
&=n\mathrm{log}\left(n\left(1+\frac{\epsilon}{n}\right)\right)-(n+\epsilon) \\
&=n\left(\mathrm{log}(n)+\mathrm{log}\left(1+\frac{\epsilon}{n}\right)\right)-(n+\epsilon) \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

For very large $n$, $\tfrac{\epsilon}{n}<1$

Taylors series for $\mathrm{log}(1+x)$ is:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{log}(1+x) &= x - \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}\pm \ldots \\
\implies \mathrm{log}(1+\tfrac{\epsilon}{n})&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{{(-1)}^{k+1}}{k} \frac{\epsilon^{k}}{n^k}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\therefore \,\,\, \mathrm{log}(t^n\mathrm{e}^{-t})&=n\Bigg(\mathrm{log}(n)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{{(-1)}^{k+1}}{k} \frac{\epsilon^{k}}{n^k}\Bigg)-n-\epsilon \\
&=n\mathrm{log}(n)-n+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{{(-1)}^{k+1}}{k} \frac{\epsilon^{k}}{n^{k-1}} \\
&=n\mathrm{log}(n)-n-\frac{\epsilon^2}{2n}+\frac{\epsilon^{3}}{3n^{2}}-\frac{\epsilon^{4}}{4n^{3}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

As this is only an approximation, take only the first term in the series,

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\therefore \,\,\, \mathrm{log}(t^n\mathrm{e}^{-t}) &\approx n\mathrm{log}(n)-n-\frac{\epsilon^2}{2n} \\
\implies t^n\mathrm{e}^{-t} &\approx \frac{n^n}{\mathrm{e}^n}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\epsilon^2}{2n}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Then putting it into our original integral:

\begin{equation}
n!=\int_0^\infty t^n\mathrm{e}^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_{-n}^\infty \frac{n^n}{\mathrm{e}^n}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\epsilon^2}{2n}}{d}\epsilon
\end{equation}

As $\int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-px^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{p}}$

\begin{equation}
n!\approx n^n\mathrm{e}^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n}
\end{equation}

Comment: I don't like how they say "for very large n, $\epsilon/n < 1$" then proceed to fix $n$ and integrate $\epsilon$ up to infinity.

Comment: Take $\epsilon$ consistently small wrt $n$, say $\epsilon = O(n^{1/2})$.

Answer (score 1):

Stirling's formula has many derivations.  Here, using the factorial function:

$$ \log N! = \sum_{n=1}^N \log n = 
\sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{m=1}^n \bigg( \log m - \log (m-1) \bigg)
 = 
\sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{m=1}^n - \log  \bigg(1 - \frac{1}{m} \bigg) $$

Then we can use the identity $\log (1+x) \approx  x$ to obtain a [Harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)):

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{m=1}^n - \log  \bigg(1 - \frac{1}{m} \bigg) \approx 
\sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m} 
= \sum_{m=1}^N \frac{N-m}{m} 
= \sum_{m=1}^N \left( N \cdot \frac{1}{m}- 1 \right)\approx N \log N - N$$